# VBA Test for Object Model

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to write a PPT macro that will work in both PPT 2010 and 2013-2016.  There is one object in the 2013-16 Object Model (`ActivateChartDataWindow`) that is not in the 2010 model that I want to use.  I thought of using code like this to test the application version and then use the correct object:

```
With theChart.ChartData
    If CInt(Application.Version) >= 15 Then
        .ActivateChartDataWindow
    Else
        .Activate
    End If
....
End With
```

The problem is this won't compile in 2010 since the `.ActivateChartDataWindow` object is not found.  So there wouldn't be run-time error, but there is a compile-time error.

What's the best way to do this?  Is there a way to disable compile-time checking in the code itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making an early-bound member call; if the code contains member calls that can't be compiled using an earlier version of a type library, then the solution is to switch to late-bound calls, which by definition are only bound at run-time (i.e. no compile-time validation).

So instead of `With theChart.ChartData`, you declare an `Object` variable, and `Set` it to `theChart.ChartData`:

```
Dim lateBoundChartData As Object
Set lateBoundChartData = theChart.ChartData
```

And now any member calls made against that `lateBoundChartData` will only be validated at run-time - watch out for typos, `Option Explicit` can't help you here!

```
With lateBoundChartData
    If CInt(Application.Version) >= 15 Then
        'no intellisense & compile-time validation here
        .ActivateChartDataWindow
    Else
        'no intellisense & compile-time validation here
        .Activate
    End If
End With
```

The funny thing is that people write late-bound code all the time, without even realizing: anything you write against `Object` is always going to be late-bound.